# UITableview scroll to top on reload goes too high?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm using scrollRectToVisible:

```
[self.tblArticle scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

and/or setContentOffset:

```
NSIndexPath* top = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:0];
    [self.tblArticle scrollToRowAtIndexPath:top atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

and/or this:

```
[self.tblArticle setContentOffset: CGPointZero animated: YES];
```

to (try to) scroll to the top of my tableView after reload. But sometimes it goes too high so that I see too much white space above the table. My table has a header that's above the cell rows.
It goes too high when I scroll down a bit and then initiate the reload. If I'm on top, the scrolling is good. But the lower I get before reloading, the more white space is visible above the header.
For now I'm calculating how low I am and then I set something like this:

```
CGFloat height = 0;
    if(self.selectedCategoryID > 2)
        height = 250;
    [self.tblArticle scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, height, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

which is veeery bad. Thanks for any suggestions!

**EDIT** I 'm using the uitableview reload like this:

```
// Reload table
[self.tblArticle reloadData];
```

[image: This is the wanted result]

[image: But I get this instead...]

Comment: Try including some screen shots of what's happening  as compared to what you expect. Are you using a refresh control to reload the table?

Comment: Hi @beyowulf. I've added some screenshots to demonstrate the problem. The first shows what I wanted to achieve and the second what I actually got.

Comment: How and where are you setting tableHeaderView?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[_mainTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_mainTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to scroll UITableview to top.

```
[mainTableView setContentOffset: CGPointZero animated: YES];
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. Tried that - same result. I''l update my question with this too. Thanks!